# tabcontrol selectedindexchanged does not fire

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a method,

```
private void uxTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}
```

It never goes through inside this method, when I click different tabs.
`uxTabControl` currently has 7 tabs, none of tabs works. Did I miss anything?

Comment: have you add this event handler to tab control `SelectedIndexChanged` event by designer or by code?

Comment: by designer: You need to try the property SelectedIndexChanged; to expose that property, with the property window open, click once outside the tabbed container then click one of the small tabs once, don't click inside the tab area. Find the property, type in an event name and then double click it.

Comment: you probably had it wired at one time but then removed event and the handler `uxTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged` became abandoned

Comment: @JohnB I don't think I've done that one. I just create a method and named this. Can you explain more detail please?

Comment: @T.S. I dodn't wire anything with this. How can I do that?

Comment: @jaykodeveloper - can't explain any clearer sorry

Comment: The fact that you have method `uxTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged` tells me that once you went into control properties window, selected events and pressed enter in `SelectedIndexChanged` (unless you copied code from somewhere). Then, somehow you removed the same and method remained while `uxTabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += uxTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged` was removed. This is just VS behavior. It keeps the method because it doesn't want you to lose the custom code you might entered there

Comment: you need to read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/creating-event-handlers-in-windows-forms) especially [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-connect-multiple-events-to-a-single-event-handler-in-windows-forms) and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-create-event-handlers-at-run-time-for-windows-forms)

Comment: @T.S. I actually copied and pasted it

Comment: I already gave you the answer - add `uxTabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += uxTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged` in constructor. Done